# What drive characteristics might be causing errors in my program?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata

I have some computers running Windows NT which collect data for an external emulator computer and writes it on a GUI. I was doing this because onsite the computers were experiencing issues like gaps in data and missing data, etc., so I could figure out the issue and fix it.

The programs were made to run overnight to see if the errors would appear. I've narrowed down the issue to the drives in the computers, I tested 3 different drives I currently use and only one of the drives doesn't present this problem when running. The drives we are using are as follows:

1. SuperTalent FTM32GL25V (Working) - MLC NAND Flash
2. Transcend TS64GSSD500 (Not working) - SLC NAND Flash
3. EXOS 7E8 7200.12 500Gb (Not working) - NOR Flash

So far it is only the SuperTalent SSD that works as expected and I can't figure out why this happens my only guess is that it may have to do with the Flash-type (indicated in the list) or data buffer size. I am trying to figure out what exactly could be causing this problem so I can purchase the proper drives. Keep in mind that I am limited to using SATA connection.

I ran a number of tests, one of which included sending data back and forth from 2 computers where it would simply write a timestamp in a text file. When the data was sent from either of the 2 faulty drives there would be characters missing in many spots (gaps) for example:

> [image: Example of data gaps in text file]

I don't have the option to change the software as it would need to be approved and it would be a lengthy process.

What the test above tells me is that this is probably not a software issue as a simple read and write program presented the same issues...

I am stuck, if anyone has any guidance it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You kept us in the dark about what errors do appear. With not much information to work on, I'd also guess it's some timing-related problem, and not a problem of "SSD not working". If there are no explicit errors, but only missing data, my money would be on a software issue (race condition or other bug), or with the SSD just not being fast enough to keep up with the write speed. One way to test this is to use *multiple*  drivers and only write a fraction of the data to each.

Comment: I'll give that a try. As you pointed out, there were no explicit errors. Only gaps in data. I ran a number of tests, one of which included sending data back and forth from 2 computers where it would simply write a time stamp in a text file. When the data was sent from either of the 2 faulty SSD's there would be characters missing in many spots (gaps). I don't have the option to change the software as it would need to be approved and it would be a lengthy process. Any idea why everything works fine on the SuperTalent SSD and not the rest? I just need to find out the proper drives to pruchase...

Comment: The Exos drives are not SSD, they just have a NOR based cache. The [actual datasheet](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/exos-7-e8-msft-data-sheetDS1957-5M-2005GB-en_GB.pdf) states a sustained data rate of "only"  215MB/s. Whether or not that is enough when shared between reads and writes depends on your programs. What kind of interaction you have sounds very much down to what your programs are doing which you've given little or no information about.

Comment: Are the missing characters complete blocks? "Missing in many spots" can be lots of things. (Also, please edit your question with additional information).

Comment: It could be that your systems are memory starved, are paging to disk a lot, and the program capturing data is only being paged back in fast enough on the SuperTalent drive.

Comment: I edited the question with an image of what I mean. It misses characters and sometimes complete blocks as if the writing stopped for a small period. I am not sure what you mean by memory starved but what characteristic of the SuperTalent drive do you think makes it so that this doesn't happen? I'm hoping that this can be an issue solved by simply purchasing the correct drives so that the issue doesn't happen again.

Comment: This honestly doesn’t seem like a drive related issue. This kind of hyper-specific data errors in your output makes me thing this is an issue with the program’s performance and not the drive itself. If the drive itself had damage you would not see such clean removal of expected data. It would look more like gibberish from a hardware failure and you could not even open the file itself.

Comment: Giacomo1968, that was my initial thought too but then why does the program work perfectly fine on the SuperTalent SSD? Also, my second test performing a simple data transfer between 2 computers is completely separate from the initial program in question.

Comment: @QuadeHowald Maybe this is a false correlation. I would recommend running it a few times on the drive that works and see what happens.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I thought the same thing, I've run the program on the SuperTalent SSD for a month at a time with no issues. I've done these tests for a few months now to try to figure out the issue and one thing that remains constant is that the issues are not present on the SuperTalent SSD but they are on the other 2... I've put the good drive on a different computer and it still doesn't give any issues. The same can't be said about the other 2. This is why I've come to the forum for help :/...

Comment: @Giacomo1968 What do you think?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no other ideas.